# innerHTML with variables angular2

Tags: angular, innerhtml

I would like to know how I can put variables inside a string and render it with Angular2 ?

Here is my code :

HTML :

```
<div [innerHTML]="testHTML"></div>
```

The variable :

```
public testHTML: string = "<h1>test - {{ variable[0] }}</h1>";
```

"variable" is an array of string, not null and containing at least 1 value.

And what I get displayed is :

> test - {{ variable[0] }}

H1 is well rendered. but my variables are not interprated !

How can I solve this ?

Comment: Why don't you just create the testHTML like  `"<h1>test - "+variable[0]+"</h1>";`

Comment: because the idea would that that this string comes from a setting on a server..

Comment: If you have that above question answer plz tell me   @carndacier . I need it. It's a server response HTML file. that file show with variable values.

Answer (score 5):

You **can't have any** Angular specific stuff in HTML added dynamically. They all work only work when added statically to a components template.

You can create components dynamically at runtime though and add such a component using `ViewContainerRef.createComponent()`

See also [Equivalent of $compile in Angular 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34784778/equivalent-of-compile-in-angular-2/37044960#37044960)

Answer (score 4):

You can try following way,

```
 variable=["Angular2","Angular1"];

 constructor(){
   this.testHTML = `<h1>test - ${this.variable[0]}</h1>`; 
 }
```

**DEMO : https://plnkr.co/edit/sGTcVAym6jKjm8i7jQgb?p=preview**

Comment: Just as note, this requires `this.testHTML = `<h1>test - ${this.variable[0]}</h1>`;` to be executed every time `variable[0]` changes.

Comment: Yes. Then n then you can get updated value. It should be parsed at TS level.

Answer (score 1):

I tested my solution in Angular 7.

To dynamically load the information from the server I did the following:

```
this.subscription = this.service.getDynamicHtml()
      .subscribe(innerHTML =>{
        this.innerHTML = <string>innerHTML;
      });
```

In the template I simply use

```
    <div [innerHTML]="innerHTML"></div>
```

In my case the server returns all of the text, but in your case if only a variable needs to be updated when the subscription ends the screen will be refreshed.

See https://alligator.io/angular/innerhtml-binding-angular/ for more details

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so as my requirement is to get this string value an API, and so on, I don't know what it will be... I've put in place a simple parser, that I will update when new needs come in.

For those who might be interested in, here is the function for the following html :     `var test = "<h1>test - {{Contact.FirstName}}</h1>";`:

```
  public retrieveValue(from: string) {

    var tmp = from.split("{{");
    for (var i = 0; i < tmp.length; i++) {

      var val = tmp[i].split("}}")[0];

      var toReplace = "{{" + val + "}}";

      var tmp1 = val.split(".");

      var final: any | string = this;
      for (var j = 0; j < tmp1.length; j++)
        final = final[tmp1[j]];

      var re = new RegExp(toReplace,"g");
      from = from.replace(re, final);
    }

    return from;
  }
```

this function doesn't work (yet) for array, but it can be extended pretty easily I think.

If this answer has at least 10 "useful" votes, I will mark it as the answer. otherwise Günter Zöchbauer's answer will be the one :)

Thanks for your help guys.

Answer (score -1):

The question is: "I would like to know how I can put variables inside a string and render it with Angular2 ?"
It can also be done like this ( a very simple version):

```
<p>
<b><span>test - </span></b>
<span>{{variable[0]}}</span>
</p>
```

... next simple version:

`// ???.component.ts`

```
item = 'text - ' + this.variable[0];
```

`// ???.component.html`

```
<h1>
<span [innerHTML]="item"></span>
</h1>
```